# Does Linux support IPv4 mapped IPv6 addresses?

Tags: linux, ipv6, ping, ipv4

I work in a mixed IPv4 / IPv6 environment. I read that IPv4 addresses can be mapped into the IPv6 space with this syntax

> ::ffff:1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4 is the IPv4 address)

Does Linux support this notation ? All these fail on my server:

```
ping6 ::ffff:1.2.3.4 # to the server IP
ping6 ::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using `ping6`, try ssh'ing to `::ffff:127.0.0.1`.

I think the specific failure here is related to `ping6`, not the IP4 mapped addresses.

Aren't IPv4 mapped IPv6 addresses actually using IPv4, and hence, not suitable for `ping6`?

Linux has a socket option, IPV6_V6ONLY which prevents some applications using IPv4 mapped addresses.  However, I think for `ping6` the specific issue is the way it works internally.

[This](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-net/2012/01/06/msg003067.html) is from netbsd, but I think it covers the issue.

> You should be aware that IPv4 mapped IPv6 is still IPv4 - it's only
>   presented in a IPv6-resembling text format (or actually, when calling
>   your operating system's libraries or kernel, binary socket address
>   format.)
>
> For dual-protocol applications this is no problem - they know how to
>   switch (implicitly, when using the right (modern) library calls).

Comment: ssh works indeed! Why would support for IPv4 mapped addresses be specifiy to each application ?

Comment: http://www.lists.apple.com/archives/ipv6-dev/2011/Oct/msg00003.html for an explanation regarding `ping6`

Comment: @GeneVincent I would expect that support for IPv4 mapped addresses is specific to libraries.  Tools like `ping6` have their own code for mapping addresses and building packets, and in the case of `ping6` I would expect it to use IPv6 ICMP packets rather than IPv4 ICMP packets.  IPv4 wouldn't recognize the ping request.